# ため used to give reason?

Tags: grammar, particles, reason

So I came across this sentence:

> 政府が情報を厳しくチェックしているため、事件のことをみんなの前で話すことができません。

I'm familiar with ために and のため, but it's the first time I see ため used like this. From my understanding, in this sentence it's used to give a reason here just like から/ので. What is the difference, and can you just replace it with から/ので?

Comment: Duplicate?: [Nuanced meaning of ため](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74938/nuanced-meaning-of-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81)

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55517/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48738/9831